# Blank page when trying to go to a controller that returns a jsp page. it all links fine

Tags: java, spring, jsp, controller

I am getting a blank page whenever trying to connect to my controller in the browser. The request mapping is right and I am returning the right jsp but nothing is being displayed on the browser other than a blank screen. 
It seems to be reaching the controller and I am getting no errors.

Dispatcher servlet

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ProjectOne" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Controller

```
  package com.ProjectOne.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
/**
 * @author SLavelle
 *
 */
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView Home() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("homepage");
        modelAndView.addObject("greetings", "Welcome to ProjectOne!");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

JSP

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>ProjectOne</title>
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/welcome.css" rel="stylesheet" >
        <h1>${greeting}</h1>
        <br>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: bit more info is needed..  like what have you made so far

Comment: I have created a controller that returns a model and view. the view is a jsp.

Comment: please attach your dispatcher-servlet.xml ,controller and jsp page code with your question

Comment: can you debug the controller, where it should reach the controller?  you should add some code snippits of your config/controller/jsp, otherwise its looking in the dark for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending `grettings` model object but you are printing`${greeting}`. Spelling mismatch.

Comment: ah okay so there was a spelling mismatch, i was sending greetings but printing greeting without the (s) cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<H1> and <br>` tags should be in the body in your JSP Page…

```
<head>
<body>
<h1>${greeting}</h1>
</body>
```

Everything in the HTML body tag is shown on screen.